# Unable to download data from tableau view

Tags: rest, ssl, postman, tableau-api

I am trying to download data from a view that I published on my company's tableau server. I tried various methods like writing a python code and using postman but none of them seem to be working.

This is the python code:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC 
import csv

# Specify Tableau Server API info
server_url = 'https://tableau.na.xom.com'
site_id = 'Chemical'
mytoken_name = 'test'
mytoken_secret = 'U3mHB/1uRMKd+/OSXlgujg==:nR3ZCf4DQwjZe9tQ5qBpXtDoBVDHnZ7y'
api_version = '3.1'

# Authenticate with Tableau Server
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(token_name=mytoken_name, personal_access_token=mytoken_secret, site_id=site_id)
server = TSC.Server(server_url, use_server_version=True)
server.version = api_version

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_views, pagination_item = server.views.get()
    view_name = [view.name for view in all_views]

    for i in range(len(view_name)):
        if view_name[i] == 'Dashboard 3':
            print(view_name[i])

    view_ids = [view.id for view in all_views]
    view_dict = {view_name[i]: view_ids[i] for i in range(len(view_ids))}
    print(view_dict)

    # view we want to download data from
    view_name = 'Dashboard 3'

    # query view id of vd
    view_id = view_dict.get(view_name)

    # set up request to download data in a specific format
    options = TSC.CSVOptions()

    # get data from the view and write to a file
    view_item = server.views.get_by_id(view_id)
    with open('{}.csv'.format(view_name), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in server.views.get_csv(view_item, options):
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

    print('Data downloaded successfully!')
```

I wrote this with the help of ChatGPT but it is completely useless, making me run around in circles, using the wrong API version or the incorrect methods.

This is what I am doing on Postman:

https://tableau.company.com/api/3.19/sites/1edc53ac-e247-4870-9fd3-6fad0ce5f84d/views/2474164d-8d37-4a4c-abc7-c2070fd25fd5/data

1. I am using a token name and a token secret created by the tableau server.
2. I have created a header authorization and provided my token secret in the format: Bearer *tokensecret*
3. I am getting error code: 401002 with this in the XML body:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api https://help.tableau.com/samples/en-us/rest_api/ts-api_3_14.xsd">
    <error code="401002">
        <summary>Unauthorized Access</summary>
        <detail>Invalid authentication credentials were provided.</detail>
    </error>
</tsResponse>
```

And in the network tooltip i'm seeing an error that says unable to verify first certificate.

Any comments and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the docs, not GPT . "You must first call the views.populate_csv method to access the CSV data." https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#views

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You can get list of views by reading documentation [here][1]:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd
import requests

tableau_user_name = '<Replace with your data>'
tableau_password = '<Replace with your data>'
personal_access_token_secret = '<Replace with your data>'
personal_access_token_name = '<Replace with your data>'
tableau_site = '<Replace with your data>'
tableau_server = '<Replace with your data>'



# tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(tableau_user_name, tableau_password,tableau_site)
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(personal_access_token_name, personal_access_token_secret,site_id = tableau_site)
server = TSC.Server(tableau_server)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)

ls = ['<Your view id>']   
    
    
    for l in ls:      
        view_item = server.views.get_by_id(f'{l}')     
        
        server.views.populate_csv(view_item)
        with open(f'{l}_output.csv','wb') as f:
            f.write(b''.join(view_item.csv))
                
        server.views.populate_pdf(view_item)        
        with open('./view_pdf.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(view_item.pdf)
```

[1]: [https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#views:~:text=.id](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#views:%7E:text=.id))-,Views,-Using%20the%20TSC